# change javascript var color

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to change the color of a javaScript String variable with the following code :

```
var test = "hi".fontcolor("red");
```

When I print this variable, it prints the following String, instead of printing "hi" in red color:

```
<font color="red">hi</font>
```

How do I use it so that it changes the font color, instead of treating the HTML tags as String values?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You're designing this all wrong. What difference does it make if a variable is named one way or another?

Comment: I have a tabular representation of the data and I need to perform specific table cell calculations with respect to variable names.

Comment: Do it without respect to variable names. Keep them as strings.

Comment: Okay, I can take the variable name as a String. Now, how do I check if this String contains a specific subset of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
name = prompt("Please enter a string")

if (/a/.test(name)) {
   alert('a');
} else if (/b/.test(name)) {
   alert('b');
} else {
   alert('nothing');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the problem is I have to look for a small subset of characters within the variable name, instead of comparing the full name of a variable to a String for equality. As far as the variable name contains a specific String sequence, the condition is true.

Comment: My answer uses regular expressions, which accounts for that. In the first statement, it tests whether the string contains a subset of 'a' in the entire string. The second does the same for the letter 'b'. You should update your question with an example and I can help you with the regular expression that you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this with your variables I suggest that for those variables where a name check is necessary you implement them as objects:

```
var abc = {
   name: "abc",
   value: someValue
};
```

Then check if the name property of the variable contains the substring by using match with a regular expression or indexOf with a string:

```
if(abc.name.match(/ab/).length > 0)
  //do something
```

Or

```
if(abc.name.indexOf("ab") >= 0)
 //do something
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much for your response. Both of the above solutions work for me, thanks much.